# explanation shell scripting code " for loop"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, unix

Can anybody explane for me whats is this loop?

```
for file in `ls *SC*`; do 
  for content in `cat $file `; do
    scid=`echo $file|awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
    printf "%-10s%s\n" $scid $content
  done
done > text1
```

Comment: Try do this question at http://superuser.com and you can use 4 spaces at the beggning of each line to make it format like `code`, see the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: You can try [eplainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=for+file+in+%60ls+*SC*%60%3B+do++++for+content+in+%60cat+%24file+%60%3B+do+++++scid%3D%60echo+%24file%7Cawk+-F%27.%27+%27%7Bprint+%241%7D%27%60%3B+++++printf+%22%25-10s%25s%5Cn%22+%24scid+%24content%3B+++done%3B+done+%3E+text1)

Comment: Use `$(…)` in place of back-quotes around a command; it is easier to get right, especially if you ever get around to nesting the notation.

Comment: It seems to be trying to showcase shell antipatterns.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop is bad written shell code (performance, errors after strange filenames).
Outer loop:

```
for file in `ls *SC*`; do 
done > text1
```

Try to find all files with SC in the name, do something with it, and write output to text1. Better is: `for file in *SC*; do`

Inner loop:

```
  for content in `cat $file `; do
  done
```

Do something with every word in the file.

```
scid=`echo $file|awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
```

This line belongs outside the inner loop. It cuts off things from the first dot (removing extension in a filename with 1 dot). You can use `cut` or faster `${file%.*}`.

```
printf "%-10s%s\n" $scid $content
```

Print the cut-off filename (minimal 10 positions: append spaces) and the first word, both can fail when scid or content have special characters (better `printf "%-10s%s\n" "$scid" "$content"`).

Comment: Better still `awk 'f != FILENAME { f=FILENAME; split(FILENAME, x, "[.]"); } { printf "%-10s%s\n", x[1], $0 }' *SC*`

Comment: @tripleee: I only tried to explain the loop, I still do not understand what is needed. Should each outputline (starting with the file-basename) have one word or one line of the input files? Yeah, awk is Always Worth Knowing.